# Problem testing the POST method on Express API with Jest and Supertest

Tags: node.js, testing

I'm developing a REST API with Express. I have only one route called 'users' which is responsible for creating new users. The API works okay; it successfully creates a new user and saves it in MongoDB. However, when I try to test it using Jest and Supertest, the object being sent is undefined.

```
const Users = require("../models/user.model");
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");
const { uid } = require("uid");

/**
 * Controlador para la creación de un nuevo usuario.
 * 
 * @param {Object} req - Objeto de solicitud HTTP.
 * @param {Object} res - Objeto de respuesta HTTP.
 * @returns {Boolean} - Devuelve false si las contraseñas no coinciden.
 * @throws {Error} - Lanza un error si ocurre algún problema durante la creación del usuario.
 */

const createUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Extraer datos de la solicitud
        const {
            email,
            password,
            password_confirm,
            militaryRank,
            name,
            lastName,
        } = req.body;

        // Comprobar si las contraseñas coinciden
        if (password !== password_confirm) {
            res.status(400).json({
                error: "Contraseña incorrecta",
                message: "La contraseña proporcionada no coincide con la contraseña almacenada. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo." 
            });
            return false;
        }

        // Crear un nuevo usuario con los datos proporcionados
        const usuario = new Users({
            email,
            password,
            militaryRank,
            name,
            lastName,
            userRole: 'current_user',
            token: uid(32),
        });

        // Cifrar la contraseña antes de guardarla en la base de datos
        const salt = bcryptjs.genSaltSync(10);
        usuario.password = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, salt);

        // Guardar el usuario en la base de datos
        await usuario.save();
        
        // Enviar respuesta exitosa
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Usuario creado correctamente",
            user: {
                email,
                militaryRank,
                name,
                lastName
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Manejar errores durante la creación del usuario
        res.status(401).json({
            error: "Error interno del servidor",
            message: error.message
        });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    createUser
};
```

```
const users = require("../models/user.model");

/**
 * Función asincrónica para validar si ya existe un correo electrónico en la base de datos.
 * 
 * @param {String} email - Correo electrónico a validar.
 * @throws {Error} - Lanza un error si el correo electrónico ya existe en la base de datos.
 */
const validateEmail = async (email) => {
   try {
       // Buscar el correo electrónico en la base de datos
       const existingEmail = await users.findOne({ email });

       // Verificar si el correo electrónico ya existe en la base de datos
       if (existingEmail) {
           // Si el correo electrónico ya existe, lanzar un error
           console.log("El correo electrónico ya existe en la base de datos");
           throw new Error("El correo electrónico ya existe en la base de datos");
       }
   } catch (error) {
       // Capturar y manejar cualquier error que ocurra durante la validación del correo electrónico
       throw new Error(error);
   }
};

module.exports = {
   validateEmail,
};
```

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
/**
 * Middleware para validar errores de validación utilizando express-validator.
 * 
 * @param {Object} req - Objeto de solicitud HTTP.
 * @param {Object} res - Objeto de respuesta HTTP.
 * @param {Function} next - Función para pasar el control al siguiente middleware o al controlador de la ruta.
 * @returns {Object} - Devuelve un objeto JSON con los errores de validación si existen.
 */
const validateError = (req, res, next) => {
    // Obtener los errores de validación de la solicitud
    let errors = validationResult(req); 

    // Verificar si hay errores de validación
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        // Imprimir los errores de validación en la consola
        console.log(errors.array());
        // Responder con un objeto JSON que contiene los errores de validación
        return res.json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    // Si no hay errores de validación, pasar el control al siguiente middleware o al controlador de la ruta
    next();
}

module.exports = {
    validateError
}
```

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
const { isEmail } = require('validator');

/**
 * Esquema del modelo de usuario.
 */
const UserSchema = Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Es necesario introducir un correo electrónico'],
        validate: [isEmail, 'Es necesario introducir un correo electrónico válido'],
        maxLength: [40, 'No debe exceder los 40 caracteres'],
        minLength: [10, 'Debe tener al menos 10 caracteres'],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Es necesario introducir una contraseña'],
        maxLength: [100, 'No debe exceder los 100 caracteres'],
        minLength: [10, 'Debe tener al menos 10 caracteres'],
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    militaryRank: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Es necesario introducir el grado militar'],
        maxLength: [50, 'No debe exceder los 50 caracteres'],
        minLength: [5, 'Debe tener al menos 5 caracteres'],
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Es necesario introducir el nombre'],
        maxLength: [20, 'No debe exceder los 20 caracteres'],
        minLength: [2, 'Debe tener al menos 2 caracteres'],
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Es necesario introducir los apellidos'],
        maxLength: [20, 'No debe exceder los 20 caracteres'],
        minLength: [2, 'Debe tener al menos 2 caracteres'],
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    userRole: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Es necesario el rol'],
        maxLength: [13, 'No debe exceder los 13 caracteres'],
        minLength: [7, 'Debe tener al menos 7 caracteres'],
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        maxLength: [32, 'No debe exceder los 32 caracteres'],
        minLength: [32, 'Debe tener al menos 32 caracteres'],
        required: [true, 'Es necesario el token']
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: [true, 'El usuario no se ha definido como activo o inactivo']
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: [true, 'Este usuario no tiene estado']
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});

module.exports = model("Users", UserSchema);
```

```
const express = require('express');

const { check } = require("express-validator");

// Helpers de validación
const { validateEmail } = require('../helpers/user.helper');
const { validateError } = require('../middlewares/validation-errors.middleware');

// Controllers
const { createUser } = require('../controllers/user.controller');

const app = express();

/**
 * Ruta para la creación de un nuevo usuario.
 * 
 * @param {String} email - El correo electrónico del usuario.
 * @param {String} password - La contraseña del usuario.
 * @param {String} password_confirm - La confirmación de la contraseña del usuario.
 * @param {String} militaryRank - El rango militar del usuario.
 * @param {String} name - El nombre del usuario.
 * @param {String} lastName - El apellido del usuario.
 */
app.post("/",[
    //check("email", "Es necesario introducir un correo electrónico").custom(validateEmail),
    check("email", "El correo electrónico está vacío").not().isEmpty(),
    check("email", "El correo electrónico no es válido").isEmail(),
    check("email", "El correo electrónico no debe tener más de 100 caracteres").isLength({ max: 100 }),
    check("email", "El correo electrónico no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres").isLength({ min: 10 }),

    check("password", "La contraseña está vacía").not().isEmpty(),
    check("password", "La contraseña no debe tener más de 100 caracteres").isLength({ max: 100 }),
    check("password", "La contraseña no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres").isLength({ min: 10 }),

    check("password_confirm", "Es necesario confirmar la contraseña").not().isEmpty(),
    check("password_confirm", "La confirmación de la contraseña no debe tener más de 100 caracteres").isLength({ max: 100 }),
    check("password_confirm", "La confirmación de la contraseña no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres").isLength({ min: 10 }),

    check("militaryRank", "Es necesario introducir el rango militar").not().isEmpty(),
    check("militaryRank", "El rango militar no debe tener más de 50 caracteres").isLength({ max: 50 }),
    check("militaryRank", "El rango militar no debe tener menos de 5 caracteres").isLength({ min: 5 }),

    check("name", "Es necesario introducir el nombre").not().isEmpty(),
    check("name", "El nombre no debe tener más de 20 caracteres").isLength({ max: 20 }),
    check("name", "El nombre no debe tener menos de 2 caracteres").isLength({ min: 2 }),

    check("lastName", "Es necesario introducir el apellido").not().isEmpty(),
    check("lastName", "El apellido no debe tener más de 20 caracteres").isLength({ max: 20 }),
    check("lastName", "El apellido no debe tener menos de 2 caracteres").isLength({ min: 2 }),

    validateError
], createUser);

module.exports = app;
```

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const csurf = require('csurf');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const { dbConnection } = require('../database/mongo.config');
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const { handleErrors } = require('../middlewares/handleErrors.middleware');
const { csrfError } = require('../middlewares/csrfError.middleware');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

class Server {

    constructor(){

        // CSRF token for all request
        csurf({ cookie: true });

        // Inicializamos express server
        this.app = express();

        // Puerto de conexión express
        this.port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

        // Middlewares de la aplicación
        this.middlewares();

        // Conexión a base de datos
        this.connectDB();

        // Rutas de la App
        this.routes();
    }

    /**
     * Conexión a la base de datos MongoDB.
     */
    async connectDB() {
        await dbConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Configuración de los middlewares de la aplicación.
     */
    middlewares(){

        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

        // Parsear peticiones JSON
        this.app.use(express.json());

        // Parsear peticiones de formularios
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

        // Cookie Parser
        this.app.use(cookieParser());

        // Manejador de Errores
        this.app.use(handleErrors);
        this.app.use(csrfError);

        // Cors middleware
        this.app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

        // FileUpload
        this.app.use(fileUpload({
            useTempFiles : true,
            tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
        }));

        // Middlewares de Helmet
        this.app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy());
        this.app.use(helmet.crossOriginEmbedderPolicy());
        this.app.use(helmet.crossOriginOpenerPolicy());
        this.app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy());
        this.app.use(helmet.dnsPrefetchControl());
        this.app.use(helmet.frameguard());
        this.app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
        this.app.use(helmet.hsts());
        this.app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
        this.app.use(helmet.noSniff());
        this.app.use(helmet.originAgentCluster());
        this.app.use(helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies());
        this.app.use(helmet.referrerPolicy());
        this.app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
    }

    /**
     * Configuración de las rutas de la aplicación.
     */
    routes(){
        this.app.use('/api/users', require('../routes/users.router'));
    }

    /**
     * Iniciar el servidor para escuchar en el puerto especificado.
     */
    listen(){
        try {
            this.app.listen(this.port, ()=>{
                console.log(`Servidor disponible en la url http://localhost:${this.port}`);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);   
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Server;
```

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../routes/users.router');

describe('POST /api/users/', () => {
    it('Debería crear un nuevo usuario y devolver un código de estado 201', async () => {
        const newuserTest = {
            "email": "example@example.com",
            "password": "password123",
            "password_confirm": "password123",
            "militaryRank": "Sargento",
            "name": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        };

        const response = await request(app)
            .post("/") 
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json') // Se configuró cada cabecera individualmente
            .set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
            .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            .set('Content-Length', '500')
            .set('Set-Cookie', 'cookie1=value1; Max-Age=3600')
            .send(newuserTest);

        expect(response.status).toEqual(201);
        expect(response.body).toEqual(newuserTest);
        // Aquí puedes realizar tus expectativas sobre la respuesta recibida
        // Por ejemplo, si esperas que la respuesta sea el mismo objeto que has enviado:
        // 
    });
});
```

And this is the error ouput from console:

```
 FAIL  test/user.router.test.js (6.987 s)
  POST /api/users/
    × Debería crear un nuevo usuario y devolver un código de estado 201 (5015 ms)                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                           
  ● POST /api/users/ › Debería crear un nuevo usuario y devolver un código de estado 201                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                           
    TypeError: Class constructor Server cannot be invoked without 'new'



  ● POST /api/users/ › Debería crear un nuevo usuario y devolver un código de estado 201

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

      3 |
      4 | describe('POST /api/users/', () => {
    > 5 |     it('Debería crear un nuevo usuario y devolver un código de estado 201', async () => {
        |     ^
      6 |         const newuserTest = {
      7 |             "email": "example@example.com",
      8 |             "password": "password123",

      at it (test/user.router.test.js:5:5)
      at Object.describe (test/user.router.test.js:4:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.14 s, estimated 8 s
Ran all test suites matching /npm|test/i.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

'This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
^C^C¿Desea terminar el trabajo por lotes (S/N)? 
^C
PS C:\Users\Danny Fernandez\Desktop\api-arcangel\src> npm test

> test
> jest  npm test

  console.log
    [
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El correo electrónico está vacío',
        path: 'email',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El correo electrónico no es válido',
        path: 'email',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El correo electrónico no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres',
        path: 'email',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'La contraseña está vacía',
        path: 'password',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'La contraseña no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres',
        path: 'password',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario confirmar la contraseña',
        path: 'password_confirm',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'La confirmación de la contraseña no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres',
        path: 'password_confirm',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario introducir el rango militar',
        path: 'militaryRank',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El rango militar no debe tener menos de 5 caracteres',
        path: 'militaryRank',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario introducir el nombre',
        path: 'name',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El nombre no debe tener menos de 2 caracteres',
        path: 'name',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario introducir el apellido',
        path: 'lastName',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El apellido no debe tener menos de 2 caracteres',
        path: 'lastName',
        location: 'body'
      }
    ]

      at log (middlewares/validation-errors.middleware.js:17:17)

  console.log
    [
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El correo electrónico está vacío',
        path: 'email',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El correo electrónico no es válido',
        path: 'email',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El correo electrónico no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres',
        path: 'email',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'La contraseña está vacía',
        path: 'password',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'La contraseña no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres',
        path: 'password',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario confirmar la contraseña',
        path: 'password_confirm',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'La confirmación de la contraseña no debe tener menos de 10 caracteres',
        path: 'password_confirm',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario introducir el rango militar',
        path: 'militaryRank',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El rango militar no debe tener menos de 5 caracteres',
        path: 'militaryRank',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario introducir el nombre',
        path: 'name',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El nombre no debe tener menos de 2 caracteres',
        path: 'name',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'Es necesario introducir el apellido',
        path: 'lastName',
        location: 'body'
      },
      {
        type: 'field',
        value: undefined,
        msg: 'El apellido no debe tener menos de 2 caracteres',
        path: 'lastName',
        location: 'body'
      }
    ]

      at log (middlewares/validation-errors.middleware.js:17:17)
```

Thanks everyone

i'm debuggin this for 2 days, but i can't find the solution, not achieve to the test works.

Anyone, can help me to fix this error? thanks a lot!!